# Does Azure Web Services support Django 3.0

Tags: django, azure, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service, azure-pipelines

I've started Django project with Azure Starter Project. It created Web Services, CI/CD pipeline and template project, which I cloned from Azure DevOps. The project from Azure has Django dependency in "requirements.txt"
`django<2,>=1.9`
Now I need to change the dependency to
`Django==3.0.6`. I've changed "requirements.txt" accordingly.
When I push my code to Azure DevOps it run Pipeline jobs and during "Install Dependencies" gives me and error

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement Django==3.0.6 (from -r Application/requirements.txt (line 1)) (from versions: 1.1.3, 1.1.4, 1.2, 1.2.1, 1.2.2, 1.2.3, 1.2.4, 1.2.5, 1.2.6, 1.2.7, 1.3, 1.3.1, 1.3.2, 1.3.3, 1.3.4, 1.3.5, 1.3.6, 1.3.7, 1.4, 1.4.1, 1.4.2, 1.4.3, 1.4.4, 1.4.5, 1.4.6, 1.4.7, 1.4.8, 1.4.9, 1.4.10, 1.4.11, 1.4.12, 1.4.13, 1.4.14, 1.4.15, 1.4.16, 1.4.17, 1.4.18, 1.4.19, 1.4.20, 1.4.21, 1.4.22, 1.5, 1.5.1, 1.5.2, 1.5.3, 1.5.4, 1.5.5, 1.5.6, 1.5.7, 1.5.8, 1.5.9, 1.5.10, 1.5.11, 1.5.12, 1.6, 1.6.1, 1.6.2, 1.6.3, 1.6.4, 1.6.5, 1.6.6, 1.6.7, 1.6.8, 1.6.9, 1.6.10, 1.6.11, 1.7, 1.7.1, 1.7.2, 1.7.3, 1.7.4, 1.7.5, 1.7.6, 1.7.7, 1.7.8, 1.7.9, 1.7.10, 1.7.11, 1.8a1, 1.8b1, 1.8b2, 1.8rc1, 1.8, 1.8.1, 1.8.2, 1.8.3, 1.8.4, 1.8.5, 1.8.6, 1.8.7, 1.8.8, 1.8.9, 1.8.10, 1.8.11, 1.8.12, 1.8.13, 1.8.14, 1.8.15, 1.8.16, 1.8.17, 1.8.18, 1.8.19, 1.9a1, 1.9b1, 1.9rc1, 1.9rc2, 1.9, 1.9.1, 1.9.2, 1.9.3, 1.9.4, 1.9.5, 1.9.6, 1.9.7, 1.9.8, 1.9.9, 1.9.10, 1.9.11, 1.9.12, 1.9.13, 1.10a1, 1.10b1, 1.10rc1, 1.10, 1.10.1, 1.10.2, 1.10.3, 1.10.4, 1.10.5, 1.10.6, 1.10.7, 1.10.8, 1.11a1, 1.11b1, 1.11rc1, 1.11, 1.11.1, 1.11.2, 1.11.3, 1.11.4, 1.11.5, 1.11.6, 1.11.7, 1.11.8, 1.11.9, 1.11.10, 1.11.11, 1.11.12, 1.11.13, 1.11.14, 1.11.15, 1.11.16, 1.11.17, 1.11.18, 1.11.20, 1.11.21, 1.11.22, 1.11.23, 1.11.24, 1.11.25, 1.11.26, 1.11.27, 1.11.28, 1.11.29)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for Django==3.0.6 (from -r Application/requirements.txt (line 1))
```

In my "requirements.txt" file I have only one line:

`Django==3.0.6`

The latest Django version in the list I see is 1.11.29. 
Does it mean Azure Pipelines can't install Django 3.0? 
If Azure Pipelines support Django 3.0 how to install it?

Thanks.

Comment: Check out this link that will help you. This is a series of 4 videos you might have to watch the previous ones to understand it properly : 
https://channel9.msdn.com/shows/Azure-Friday/Python-on-Azure-Part-3-CICD-with-Azure-Pipelines?ocid=AID754288&wt.mc_id=CFID0239
Hope it helped

Comment: Thanks @Matthieu-OD watching CI/DI episode of Azure Friday got me on the right track.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Watching [Python on Azure: Part 3—CI/CD with Azure Pipelines | Azure Friday](https://youtu.be/OMtpVqzpJ9w) got me on the right track.

I couldn't install latest version of Django because Python version for the pipeline was set to Python 2.0. So make sure that your Python version in the Pipeline test is correct.

To change the Python version in your Pipeline test go to Azure DevOps, and select the pipeline that has a problem with Django version.

[edit plieline sequence](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pVeCJ.png)

Click "Edit" button at the top right corner and in the job sequence select "Use Python x.x". Change it to the python version you're developing your application with.

That should do it for the test. But not for final deployment. Now you need to update Python, PIP and Django in Azure. Got to Azure > Kudu > CMD and update all dependencies there.

To get there in your Azure select App Service you're working on and go to "Advanced Settings". There click "Go" and you'll find Kudo CMD in the "Debug Console" drop down.